# How to create keyboard shortcut for "go to desktop"?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I tried using *hide all normal windows* but it doesn't do anything after the first time, and after looking through some previous questions I tried to find *hide all windows and show desktop* but couldn't find that option.

I'm looking for something like what <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> does in Windows.

Comment: What about ctrl + windows + d ?

Comment: @pomsky please post an answer and let me know when you do!

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Super + D shows Desktop, credit to pomsky (in comment above)